# how to query job batches info bulk api 2.0

Tags: apex, bulk-api, httprequest, httpresponse

Before, using bulk api 1.0 endpoint. I could make request to get all job's batches like so: `

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:BulkApi' + '/' + jobId + '/batch');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
req.setHeader('X-SFDC-Session', getAccessToken());

HttpResponse res = httpInstance.send(req);`
```

Is there anyway to do it with bulk api 2.0? I know the url is different however, in documentation there is no trace of similar 'batch' endpoint so I am wondering how can I retrieve batches info for job created using bulk api 2.0

For any help, directions I would be really grateful.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upload_data.htm > 5. Check the job status and results.

Comment: That link is for Bulk API 1.0. Not Bulk API 2.0.  Bulk API 2.0 does not give you batch info.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, previous answer and link in comment to the question was only relevant to Bulk API 1.0. You can see where I got this right in the following [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349316/how-to-get-batch-count-for-a-bulk-api-v2-job).

In short, [Bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_intro.htm) does not provide a way to get batch info as it now auto-batches for you.

> Salesforce provides an additional API, Bulk API 2.0, which uses the
> REST API framework to provide similar capabilities to Bulk API. **Bulk
> API 2.0 removes the need for creating and monitoring batches**, and lets
> you load record data for a job directly.

Comment: Do you know if you can use v47.0 version if your Salesforce org is currently lower than that? For example, 45.0 using 47.0 Rest API?

Comment: No but currently all the orgs should be on 51.0

Comment: The link is not relevant. Bulk API 2.0 does not give you batch count.

Comment: Thanks @kratos. Funny enough, I guess I got smarter in the year as I answered your question right but got this one wrong. Updated it to reflect correct information.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Thank you. I upvoted the answer again;)