# How to get batch count for a Bulk API v2 Job?

Tags: rest-api, batch, bulk-api

Looking at Bulk API 2.0 and Bulk API Developer Guide, I did the following:

1. [Create a job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/create_job.htm)
2. [Upload Job Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/upload_job_data.htm)
3. [Closed Job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/close_job.htm)

I am now interested in knowing how many batches have been created for the job. The problem is that for Bulk API v2 that information is not available.

Only [thing I saw was](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_get_info_all.htm)

```
/services/async/APIversion/job/jobid/batch
```

But that is for v1 bulk API and will not get the batch info for v2 bulk api jobs.

The only [thing I have to use](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/get_job_info.htm) is: `/services/data/vXX.X/jobs/ingest/jobID`

But that does not give batch count info.

Going crazy I even looked at the [limits endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) for `DailyBulkApiBatches` and that gives no indication or breakdown of batches. Just limits as it says :)

I saw a similar question at [how to query job batches info bulk api 2.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282243/how-to-query-job-batches-info-bulk-api-2-0) but that does not seem like the right answer as that is getting info about bulk api query jobs only.

And between the 3 API's that are provided dealing with Bulk API jobs, this inconsistency by Salesforce is a bit odd.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big difference between *Bulk API* and *Bulk API 2.0* is that in the former, you decide how to divide the data set into batches while the latter automatically does it for you (10,000 records).

This is mentioned in [How Requests Are Processed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/how_requests_are_processed.htm):

> While processing ingest jobs, Salesforce Bulk API 2.0 automatically
> divides your job’s data into multiple batches to improve performance.
>
> Salesforce creates a separate batch for every 10,000 records in your
> job data, up to a daily maximum of 150,000,000 records.

Your specific question is actually answered in [Work with Batches](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_intro.htm)

> Salesforce provides an additional API, Bulk API 2.0, which uses the
> REST API framework to provide similar capabilities to Bulk API. **Bulk
> API 2.0 removes the need for creating and monitoring batches**, and
> lets you load record data for a job directly.

This explains that what you're noting is expected and there is no mechanism for monitoring batches in Bulk API 2.0.